# Opening pdf over ssh in Mac terminal

Tags: pdf, ssh

As the title says, I do

```
> ssh user@host.de 
Password:     
> cd documents/ 
> okular example.pdf 
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I connect to an OpenSUSE machine over SSH from a MAC OS.

Comment: Try `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y`, if okular is a X11 application.

Comment: … and make sure Xquartz is running on the Mac

Comment: Xquartz is installed on the Mac, but the same error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, we can see the contents of the PDF over ssh using only the `less` command. One can also use [rsync](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps) to get the PDF from remote system to the local system and view it.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I still think it should work with X11 as well somehow though.

Answer (score 1):

I understand it wrongly first. Try first

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

And run your ssh, this might help.

Comment: Still the same error @Udhy

Comment: did you put this command first and followed your standard ssh step?

Comment: Yes I did, 
`>export DISPLAY=:0   
 >ssh user@host.de    
Password:    
>okular d01-x01-y03.pdf   
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display   
Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: Have you try to install X11vnc before this on your Mac. 

http://macappstore.org/x11vnc/

Install and try the same format. It should help as exporting display:0 syncs with your current machine, you can also try display:1 before giving a try with x11vnc

Comment: Also check this: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=241338 if you have some other issue too.